# Does the entire web app or the entire site collection reside in a content db?

Tags: content-database

[MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263267%28v=office.15%29.aspx) paragraph:

> All sites in a site collection are stored together in the same SQL
>   database.
>
> Keep extremely active sites in separate site collections.
>
> Because all content in a site collection is stored in the same content
>   database, the performance of database operations — such as backing up
>   and restoring content — will depend on the amount of content across
>   the site collection, the size of the database, the speed of the
>   servers hosting the database, and other factors.

Isnt it that the web application is assigned a content db (when creating a new web app we assign a content db to it) and thus all site collections reside in that same db?

Answer (score 1):

Several site collections can reside in a single content database. This is what usually happens when a web application is created and all site collections go into the single content database. However, a site collection can have a separate content database. Moreover, a site collection cannot be split into more than one database.

See these for more info:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328(v=office.15).aspx
http://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/create-a-site-collection-in-a-new-content-database-with-powershell/